# Arduino Micro triggering with no contact

Tags: arduino

I'm using an Arduino Micro to trigger specific events on a front end I have.  For some reason, however, some of the key combos are just triggering randomly.  I am not even touching the arduino when this happens.

I have it set up so when you press a button, it only triggers the key stroke once, rather than repeating it while the button is pressed.

Am I missing something, or screw something up?

```
int escButton = 12, valEsc, valEsc2, stateEsc;
int volUp = 11, valVup, valVup2, stateVup;
int volDown = 10, valVdown, valVdown2, stateVdown;
int rebootButton = 9, valReboot, valReboot2, stateReboot;

char ctrlKey = KEY_LEFT_GUI;
char shiftKey = KEY_LEFT_SHIFT;

void pressKeyCombos(int combo){
 switch(combo) {
   case 1:
       Keyboard.press(KEY_ESC);
       delay(100);
       Keyboard.releaseAll();
   break;

   case 2:
       Keyboard.press(shiftKey);
       Keyboard.press(KEY_F1);
       delay(100);
       Keyboard.releaseAll();
   break;

   case 3:
       Keyboard.press(shiftKey);
       Keyboard.press(KEY_F3);
       delay(100);
       Keyboard.releaseAll();
   break;

   case 4:
       Keyboard.press(shiftKey);
       Keyboard.press(KEY_F2);
       delay(100);
       Keyboard.releaseAll();
   break;
 }
}

void setup() {
     pinMode(escButton, INPUT);
     stateEsc = digitalRead(escButton);
     Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop(){
     valEsc = digitalRead(escButton);
     delay(10);
     valEsc2 = digitalRead(escButton);

     valVup = digitalRead(volUp);
     delay(10);
     valVup2 = digitalRead(volUp);

     valVdown = digitalRead(volDown);
     delay(10);
     valVdown2 = digitalRead(volDown);

     valReboot = digitalRead(rebootButton);
     delay(10);
     valReboot2 = digitalRead(rebootButton);

     if (valVup == valVup2) {                 
       if (valVup != stateVup) {           
         if (valVup == LOW) {              
           pressKeyCombos(4);
         }
       }
       stateVup = valVup;
     }

     if (valVdown == valVdown2) {                 
       if (valVdown != stateVdown) {           
         if (valVdown == LOW) {              
           pressKeyCombos(3);
         }
       }
       stateVdown = valVdown;
     }

     if (valReboot == valReboot2) {                 
       if (valReboot != stateReboot) {           
         if (valReboot == LOW) {              
           pressKeyCombos(2);
         }
       }
       stateReboot = valReboot;
     }

     if (valEsc == valEsc2) {                 
       if (valEsc != stateEsc) {           
         if (valEsc == LOW) {              
           pressKeyCombos(1);
         }
       }
       stateEsc = valEsc;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs are high impedance by default.  From your description of the beahvior, I can guess that you have not added external pull up/down resistor and that the pins are connected to a normally open switch.  The random input would be just as expected and noted in docs for digitialRead():

> Note
>
> If the pin isn't connected to anything, digitalRead() can return
>   either HIGH or LOW (and this can change randomly).
>
> [see reference page for digitialRead()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalRead)

The micro does have the ability to provide an internal pull up.
Your code does not show you have enabled the internal pull up resistors.  This is accomplished in a manner that may seem odd, by writing to the input pin.  From the Arduino docs:

> There are also convenient 20K pullup resistors built into the Atmega
>   chip that can be accessed from software. These built-in pullup
>   resistors are accessed in the following manner.
>
> pinMode(pin, INPUT);           // set pin to input
>   digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);       // turn on pullup resistors
>
> [see Digital Pins](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)

So in your case, add four digitalWrite()'s in the setup() to enable the pull ups and you look good to go.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot pull up resistors.  Thank you so much!  Works like a charm!